# Generate dummies if string value matches any row in particular column using pandas.dataframe.str.contains()

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

If string in "Language_cat" list matches any rows in "Languages" column in df_dat dataframe then generate dummies for that value corresponding to same row:

```
Language_cat = ['english','french','deutsch','italian','russian','spanish']

for j in Language_cat:
df_dat[j+'lang_cat'] = df_dat['Languages'].apply(lambda x: 1 if df_dat.Languages.str.contains(j) else 0)
```

However, this is the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Any particular error?

Comment: IIUC you can just do `df_dat['Languages'].str.contains('|'.join(Language_cat)).astype(int)`

Comment: Have you looked into [pd.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)?

Comment: @EdChum : It doesn't work.  TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have mentioned the error in the question post

Comment: @ayhan I have used get dummies before. It does not apply in this situation.

Comment: That sounds like you have missing values or other non string like dtype can you check your data

Comment: @EdChum It does have lot of missing values

Comment: Then you need to decide what to do with these, either drop them or filter these first or convert in 2 steps

Comment: @EdChum I filled up missing values and then ran this:

for j in Language_cat:
    df_dat[j+'lang_cat'] = df_dat['Langu'].str.contains(j).astype(int)

it works. Thanks a lot for your help. You can post it as a answer and mark it as correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Language_cat = ['english','french','deutsch','italian','russian','spanish']

for j in Language_cat:
    df_dat[j+'lang_cat'] = df_dat['Languages'].str.contains(j).astype(int)
```